# pandas dataframe find nth non isnull row

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to know how many points in a pandas dataframe where index is a series of dates that I need to have in order to end up with X points after doing a dropna(). I want the latest points. Example:

```
window = 504
s1 = pd.DataFrame(stuff)
len(s1.index) --> 600
dropped_series = s1.dropna()
len(dropped_series.index) --> 480
diff_points_count = len(s1.index) - len(dropped_series.index)
final_series = s1.tail(window + diff_points_count).dropna()
```

--> len(final_series.index) does not necessarily equal the window. Depends on where the NaN's are.

I need it to work where s1 is either a pandas.Series or a pandas.DataFrame

Comment: Sorry are you after finding the longest valid range?

Comment: No - an example is that I need exactly 504 valid points for every column in a dataframe, but I pull 600 for each column from my database b/c when I combine them they may have nan's in different place, so I want exactly 504 after I do df.dropna() on the dataframe. But I can't just do what I did above b/c the len(final_series.index) is not guaranteed to be 504 (it depends if the nan's were inside my last 504 points from the database or not).

Comment: You've not explained what you're expecting, you have 120 `NaN` row values your window is larger than your valid data points so what do you want? Are you going to impute missing values, forward fill, back fill, fill with mean, etc..?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't put the constraints in your database query, so that you're only retrieving rows where the values you care about are not `NULL`?

Comment: Yes - b/c the series can be of different frequency, so I need the nulls to understand what's a holiday and what is a frequency differency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, but I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do it:

```
    all_series_df = pd.concat([harmonized_series_set[i] for i in series_indices], axis=1)
    all_series_df['is_valid'] = all_series_df.apply(lambda x: 0 if np.any(np.isnan(x)) else 1, raw=True, axis=1)
    valid_point_count = all_series_df['is_valid'].sum()
    all_series_df['count_valid'] = valid_point_count - all_series_df['is_valid'].cumsum() + 1
    matching_row_array = all_series_df.loc[all_series_df['count_valid'] == (window + output_length - 1)]
    matching_row_index = 0
    if isinstance(matching_row_array, pd.DataFrame) and len(matching_row_array.index) > 0:
        matching_row_index = all_series_df.index.get_loc(matching_row_array.index[0])
    tail_amount = len(all_series_df.index) - matching_row_index
    for i, arg in enumerate(args):
        if i in series_indices:
            tailed_series = harmonized_series_set[i].tail(tail_amount)
            harmonized_args.append(tailed_series)
        else:
            harmonized_args.append(arg)
    return tuple(harmonized_args)
```